# Possible Android autocomplete bug on twice backspace (changing value to include previous word)

Tags: android, react-native

This is possibly just an Android 6.0 bug. I tested the snack below in Android 5.1.1 and Android 7.0 and it didn't happen there.

I am trying to do an autocomplete whenever the user types "@". I successfully do this, however once I backspace a couple times, the value on the native side becomes some value I never had before. I have simplified the case to this code below:

Please try the snack here - https://snack.expo.io/@noitsnack/what-the-heck---autocomplete-then-backspace-bug  OR copy and paste the code into a new `react-native init` project. I tested in RN 0.51 and RN 0.54.

1. Please then type `Hi @`
2. You will see it autocompletes to `Hi @foobar`.
3. Then backspace once and it properly is now `Hi @fooba`.
4. Backspace again, and now it is `Hi @foHi` (this is the bug, it should be `Hi @foob`)

This is a controlled input. I have no idea why it's turning into `Hi @foHi` on second backspace. If I blur then come after step 3 it doesn't come back.

I tried on two other devices, Android 7.0 and Android 5.1.1, and this bug was not there. It only happened on my Android 6.0. I think this is a OS dependent bug. Does anyone have ideas on what is actually going on? That will help me on how to work around this on all devices.

Is this really a bug on RN side?

I recorded a screencast of this behavior here in HD:

https://gfycat.com/RectangularAltruisticEuropeanfiresalamander

Here is a GIF:

[image: Animation]

The code (copied from the expo snack):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native'

class FieldMentionable extends Component<Props, State> {
    state = {
        value: ''
    }

    render() {
        const { value } = this.state;

        return <TextInput onChange={this.handleChange} value={value} multiline />
    }

    handleChange = ({ nativeEvent:{ text }}) => {
        const { value } = this.state;

        if (text.endsWith(' @')) this.setState(() => ({ value:text + 'foobar' }));
        else this.setState(() => ({ value:text }));
    }

    handleRef = el => this.input = el;
}


export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FieldMentionable />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        paddingHorizontal: 100,
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your snack and couldn't see the bug happening. Did you check android logs. Is there anything not usual? Maybe a deleting the app completely and reinstalling might help. Are the other android phones you tried have the same OS version?

Comment: Thanks @bennygenel - on my Android 7.0 device this didn't happen, but on my Android 6.0 device this happend. Which version was your OS?

Comment: I should have been more clear. I tried it on snack not on a real device or a simulator. I just wanted to see if this is some random issue or not. Does it happen on different version OS simulators or just on real devices?

Comment: Thanks for that clarification @bennygenel - I am on a AMD machine so I can't use emulators too well. I am only testing on these two devices, one Android 7.0 and other Android 6.0.

Comment: I just got a third device which is Android 5.1.1 and this bug did not happen there either. This is so funky. If it's not an Android 6.0 bug, is it possible this is a device specific bug?

Comment: I don't know much but this feels like a performance issue. Somewhere in the middle the value changes. A better test would be a different 6.0 device test and see if the bug also happens there. I want to test it on a emulator but the computer I'm on doesn't have any setups. I'll try it tomorrow if nobody tries it before me.

Comment: Thanks very much @bennygenel - I also tried creating a production build of the `react-native init` on my Android 6.0 project and it also happened there.

Comment: I can't help at the moment (I also have an AMD machine at home) but when I head into work this morning I'll grab one of our test devices with 6.0 on it and try to see what is going on.

Comment: Thank you so very much @ajthyng for offering to help! I sincerely appreciate it!! It would be awesome to see what OS you tested on and what result you got, if possible. Really appreciate it!

Comment: I run into behavior like this almost constantly typing on disqus loaded in chrome webpage … pixel xl android 9

Comment: @charley we're pretty sure its a bug, it hasn't been addressed yet, it would be awesome if you could post this finding here - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19085

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug on and its root issue has been filed here - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19085